# defined(VARIABLE) not evaluated correctly by MSVC?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, c-preprocessor

Running the following code

```
#include <iostream>

#define FOO
#define BAR defined(FOO)

int main() {
#if BAR
    std::cout << "BAR enabled!" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "BAR disabled!" << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

in [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/CJR20765) displays `Bar disabled!`, while running the same code in [gcc](http://rextester.com/UGB49419) or [clang](http://rextester.com/PSZH59857) displays `Bar enabled!`.

**Is this a bug in the Microsoft compiler? What is correct according to the standard?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is undefined behavior according to the standard.

[[cpp.cond]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.cond#8), emphasis mine

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the `defined` unary operator), just as in normal text. **If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process** or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, **the behavior is undefined**.